# Why C=A.append('1') doesn't work in Python

Tags: python

> A=['1']
>   C=A.append('1')
>   print C

Why is the above code return **None** but not **['1', '1']** in Python ?

Comment: The `append` function clearly doesn't work quite like you expect. Have you look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why you are not getting anything back is because the **append method has no return value**.

You could do:

```
    A=['1']
    C=A
    C.append('1')
    print(C)
```

Then you should get the right answer for your case that you are expecting to get.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the `append` method mutates the list it was called on but does not return it. There's not much reason to either, since you already have a reference to the list.